# How to build docker images in multi-module maven project via spotify plugin?

Tags: java, maven, docker

I have a maven project that consists of 2 modules with the following structure:

```
pom.xml
  |
  x----module-1
  |      |
  |      x----pom.xml
  |
  x----module-2
         |
         x----pom.xml
```

I want to build both modules as docker images and push them to a docker registry.

Here's what I have in the child poms:

**Module 1**

```
<build>
    <finalName>module-1</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <baseImage>openjdk:8-jre-alpine</baseImage>
                <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/opt/${project.build.finalName}.war"]</entryPoint>
                <serverId>docker-hub</serverId>
                <registryUrl>http://10.100.25.216:5000/v2/</registryUrl>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/opt</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.war</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Module 2**

```
<build>
    <finalName>module-2</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <baseImage>openjdk:8-jre-alpine</baseImage>
                <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/opt/${project.build.finalName}.war"]</entryPoint>
                <serverId>docker-hub</serverId>
                <registryUrl>http://10.100.25.216:5000/v2/</registryUrl>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/opt</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.war</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But when I build the project with the following command:

`mvn clean package docker:build -DpushImage`

I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build (default) on project spotify: Exception caught: Must specify baseImage if dockerDirectory is null -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

As far as I know, I need to configure parent pom to run the submodule builds, but don't have a clue on how to do it.

**P.S.** I found solutions that were involving Dockerfile-s to the project, but I would prefer maven only version if possible, using the plugin only. Is there any way?

Comment: You can use https://dmp.fabric8.io/ instead of spotify...

Comment: Did you manage to solve this one?

Comment: I didn't manage with spotify plugin, but I did a valid configuration using fabric's docker plugin, if you need I can leave it as an answer to this question

Comment: That might be helpful to someone in the future, Carmine.

Comment: @Carmine Could you post the solution , what approach you took ?